# 'dialogclose' event does not works on ui-dialog widget extension

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-widgets, jquery-widget-factory

I have this problem and I hope someone can help me.

I extend the **'Ui.dialog'** widget, making a new widget, **'qui.qdialog'**:

```
$ .widget ( ' qui.qdialog ', $ .ui.dialog , {
   options: {
            AutoOpen : false,
            height: 'auto',
            modal : true
            }
} ) ;
```

Then I generate a dialog :

```
dialog1= $ (' .selector ' ) qdialog (). ;
```

OK , now, **I bind an event listener to the 'dialogclose' event** :

```
dialog1.on ( ' dialogclose ', function (event) { console.log ( ' Yeah! '); } ) . ; // not works!
```

**This does not works , can not find the event " dialogclose " on the object.**

[Checkout on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FabainHioc/8mcbeone/)

**Note :** I do so for good reasons.
If we generate a dialog from ui.dialog ( from the 'parent' ) directly , everything works perfectly.
Initialize the dialog with the close callback specified , works perfectly :

```
$ .widget ( ' qui.qdialog ', $ .ui.dialog , {
   options: {
            AutoOpen : false,
            height: 'auto',
            modal : true,
            close : function ( ) { console.log ( ' Yeah! '); } // works !
            }
} ) ;
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you create a demo in jsfiddle by any chance? The events look right ...

Comment: Thanks for your interest , here is the link to jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/FabainHioc/8mcbeone/

Comment: What is this "qui.qdialog" that you're using? The docs don't show anything like that.

Comment: Is a "qdialog" widget in the "qui" namespace. Is the same as: $.widget( "custom.superDialog", {} ); Checkout: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/